# 100vh Doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a 100% height & width header image on my website, and I have been researching different ways to do this, and I came across the "100vh" method, however it only displays at 50% the width of my browser and 100% the height.

http://gyazo.com/07e4861fa3300c22ce7bafc265b15421

```css
.headercontainer{
 background: #000;
 width: 100vh;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="headercontainer">
</div>
```

I've also tried 200vh and that is too wide.

Answer (score 7):

1 `vh` is one percent of the **height**.

For the width, you want `vw`:

```
width: 100vw;
```

See [Viewport Relative Units in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

Comment: With this, it still seems to be wider than 100% of the browser

Comment: Did you set the margin and padding to 0 ?

Comment: @CallumWatson That's because the `body` element has a default margin of `8px`. Remove that - `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: The body's margin & padding is set to 0

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get a 100% width and height div is to first set body and html to 100% height so

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
```

Then giving the headercontainer class a height and width of 100% should work. One thing to note is that different browsers have padding and margin settings by default so setting those to zero for the body and html is also a good idea.

Another trick for percentage sizing is adding `box-sizing: border-box` to a class.  That will take into account the padding of an element and include it as the entire width, otherwise if you tell an element to have a 100% width and 10px of padding it will take 100% of the screen width in pixels and then add those extra 10px from either side to width and throw everything off.

Comment: +1 for `box-sizing`.  I can't believe I've missed that all this time and had to find workarounds like divs inside of divs!